# PSTricks, draw line only knowing one point.

Tags: pstricks

I would like to use PSTricks to draw a line. However, I only have one point, but I know at which angle I want to draw the line, and how long I want it.

Is there some way to draw a line from a point (x,y) at a given angle, for a given length?

Are there any macro packages that would help me out here?

Comment: The title may be better phrased as "In PSTricks, how to draw a line from a point at a given slope angle?"

Answer (score 6):

PSTricks has polar coordinates: see page 13 in the [manual](http://www.tex.uniyar.a).

```
\SpecialCoor
\psline[linewidth=2pt](4;50)(0,0)(4;10)
\psarc[arcsepB=2pt]{->}{3}{10}{50}
```

produces [image]

which will require that you move the coordinate system so that the origin is at the point you have.

Otherwise, you could use the more elaborate options of `\SpecialCoor`, listed at pp. 72. specifically the `([par]node)` notation which describes

> The position relative to node determined using the `angle`, `nodesep` and `offset` parameters. E.g., `([angle=45]A)`,

but requires that you define the current point you have as a named node (not so painful).

Thus:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}


\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(4,5)
\pnode(1,1){Y}
\SpecialCoor
\psline(Y)([angle=30,nodesep=2]Y)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

creates:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

it is possible to draw a vectorline which always starts at the last current point. It needs only one coordinate the other one is the current point. All points are internally saved as nodes, which can be used later.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add,multido}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid,linewidth=1pt](10,10.4)
 \psStartPoint[A](1,1)% nodes have the base name A
 \psVector(3;30)\psVector(4;60)\psVector[linecolor=red](3;10)
 \psVector[linestyle=dashed](4;110)
 \psline{->}(A0)(A4)

 \psStartPoint[B](1,1)\psset{markAngle}% nodes have the base name B
 \psVector[linestyle=dashed](4;110)
 \psVector[linecolor=red](3;10)
 \psVector(4;60)\psVector(3;30)

 \multido{\iA=0+1}{5}{\uput[0](A\iA){A\iA}\uput[180](B\iA){B\iA}}
 \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How to make a series of `\psVector`s enclosed by `\pscustom` still work? In my attempt, all the tails become at the same point rather than what they are supposed to be.

Comment: I do not really understand what you want to achieve. However, I cannot test anything in the next few weeks, I have no running TeX system

Comment: Actually I want to  use `\psVector`s inside the `\pscustom` for [my answer here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63730/9467). But they do not work in `\pscustom`. As a replacement, I used `\rlineto` and it works.

Comment: there is absolutely no need for using `\psVector` inside a `\pscustom` ...

Answer (score 3):

you need to know a little bit of postscript language and reverse polish notation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\def\xA{1}
\def\yA{2}
\def\Length{4}
\def\Angle{45} % angles are in degrees
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(6,6)
\psgrid
% define point A
\cnode*(\xA,\yA){0pt}{A}%
% define point B 
\cnode*(! \Length\space \Angle\space cos mul \xA\space add \Length\space \Angle\space  sin mul \yA\space add){0pt}{B}%
% draw line
\psline[linewidth=1pt](A)(B)%
\end{pspicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In TikZ, this is as simple as dropping into polar coordinates for some part of the path: `\tikz \draw (0,0) -- (1,1) -- ++(canvas polar cs:angle=90,radius=1cm) -- +(1,0);` or, concisely, `\tikz \draw (0,0) -- (1,1) -- ++(90:1cm) -- +(1,0);`. Is there not a similar way to use polar coordinates with PStricks that doesn't involve manually invoking `cos` and `sin`?

Comment: it is never bad to know a little bit more than the proposed "easy" techniques.

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest method is to use `\SpecialCoor`, polar coordinate form, and `origin` option as illustrated in the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](5,5)
\SpecialCoor
% draw a line from a point (1,2) at angle 45 degrees and of length 3 unit. 
\psline[origin={1,2}](3;45)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

---

### Output:

[image]

---

### Edit 1:

To make sure the line length is 3 cm, I draw a red circle of radius 3 cm.

[image]

Comment: I believe my answer is the simplest one. :-)