# Draw lines by specifying angles?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'd like to be able to draw lines in LaTeX by specifying an angle, rather than specifying it like so

```
\put(0,0){\line(2,1){3}}
```

Is this possible? I've looked at `tikz` and `tikz-euclid`. I've even tried installing `tikz-euclid`, but I couldn't even do that (I found [these](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Installing_Extra_Packages) but couldn't find the `.ins` for `tikz-euclid`). And I'm not sure if that's what I want anyway.

What do I need to do to accomplish this?

Comment: Drawing a line by knowing a point and a slope: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6000/9467, drawing chained lines by knowing a point and slopes relative to the previous line: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7788/9467

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can read about it in the [pgf manual](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf), **Section 13: Specifying Coordinates**.

An example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Draw a line at 30 degrees and of length 3
    \draw (0,0) -- (30:3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can also use the relative coordinates:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Draw the first line with absolute coordinates and the 
    % second with relative coordinates to the first line
    \draw (0,0) -- (30:3cm) -- ++(80:3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: This is like some kind of special magic. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome, although I could not find, how to specify a relative angle to the previous line. If you find it, please post here. :)

Comment: As a note, this only works when the line originates at the origin. So the example is correct if it starts at (0,0) but if you were to write `\draw (-2,0) -- (30:3cm);` the line has the wrong angle. It points toward the end point it _would_ have if it started at the origin.

Comment: The point is that `(30:3cm)` defines a point in polar coordinates with respect to the origin. What want in this case is to use relative coordinates and to preceed the coordinate with `++`. So, the command in your case is `\draw (-2,0) -- ++(30:3cm);`

Answer (score 11):

Here is a very minimal example showing how this can be done using [`pstricks`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(4,4)
  \psgrid % For reference; shows a coordinate grid
  \SpecialCoor % Allows for specifying polar coordinates (r;t)
  \psline(0,0)(4;65)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}​
```

`\SpecialCoor` adds a polar coordinate reference to the existing Cartesian `(x,y)`-coordinate specification. The difference is specified using `(r;t)` (`r` = length; `t` = angle) rather than `(x,y)`. Measurements in the above MWE is in centimetres (default).