# Changing display angle of a node label

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a diagram in TikZ with 45-degree lines, and I want to label these lines in such a way that the text of the label is also angled at 45 degrees. However I'm also interested in how to set it to a general angle. Basic example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\draw[thick] (-3,3) -- (3,-3)
\end{document}
```

I want to create labels at either end of this line, which have been rotated -45 degrees from horizontal, and which lie above-right of the line. Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows your attempts. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and provide a solution when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Stromael Please take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43894/draw-lines-by-specifying-angles

Comment: @Papiro The linked question isn't a duplicated one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are searching the option `sloped`:

Here an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick] (-3,3) -- (3,-3) node[at end,sloped,anchor=west] {foobar};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

To specify the position of the label you can use the option `pos`:

```
\draw[thick] (-3,3) -- (3,-3) node[pos=0.7,sloped,anchor=west] {foobar};
```

---

You can also use the library `decoration` to add material to a path:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[label/.style={%
   postaction={ decorate,transform shape,
   decoration={ markings, mark=at position .7 with \node #1;}}}]
\draw[,label={[above]{$r=0$}}]  (0,2.5) to [out=0,in=220] (3.25,3.75); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks, that's nearly what I need. Is there a way to alter at which point/node the label is fixed? (i.e., not just the start or end point of the line, but some point in the middle)

Comment: Is there a way to apply the same command to a curve? E.g.,
{\draw[thick] (0,2.5) to [out=0,in=220] (3.25,3.75)  node[pos=0.7, sloped, anchor=west] {$r=0$};}

Comment: Is there any way of just fixing a node and rotating the label around it by a desired angle? It's just that I have several curves to label in a similar way, and I am unsure how to adapt your code to an example with more than one curve and label.

Comment: @Stromael: You should ask a new question.

Comment: You're quite right, and in fact this has already been answered [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115554/how-to-rotate-a-tikz-label) (for anybody else who happens to need an answer). Thanks anyway.