# How to make a recursive macro in (La)TeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, grouping, recursion

The following MWE is the code of my attempt translating [my working algorithm in C#](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63591/9467) to (La)TeX. I don't understand why it does not work. Can you probe the source of problem?

Remarks:

1. `#1` is a list of binary elements. Either character `1` (move upward) or `0` (move to the right) will be appended to this list recursively. In the beginning it is an empty list.
2. `#2` represents the remaining number of movements to the right.
3. `#3` represents the remaining number of movements upward.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen,pgf}

\parindent=0pt

\newcommand{\Populate}[3]%
{%
        \ifthenelse{#2=0}% on the most left border?
        {% 
                \ifthenelse{#3=0}% on the most top border?
                {% 
                        #1\endgraf% I need to trim the most left comma later!
                }%
                {% 
                        % move upward
                        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ups}{#3-1}%
                        \Populate{#1,1}{#2}{\ups}%
                }%  
        }%      
        {% 
                \ifthenelse{#2=#3}% on the diagonal border?
                {%
                        % move to the right
                        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rights}{#2-1}%
                        \Populate{#1,0}{\rights}{#3}%
                }%
                {%
                        % move to the right
                        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rights}{#2-1}%
                        \Populate{#1,0}{\rights}{#3}%
                        % move upward
                        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ups}{#3-1}%
                        \Populate{#1,1}{#2}{\ups}%
                }%
        }%      
}


\begin{document}
\Populate{}{4}{4}
\end{document}
```

It produced a wrong output as follows:

```
,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1
,0,0,0,1,1,1,1
,0,0,1,1,1,1
,0,1,1,1,1
```

The expected output must be as follows: (the leading comma will be removed later)

```
,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1
,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1
,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1
,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1
,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1
,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1
,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1
,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1
,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1
,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1
,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1
,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1
,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1
,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1
```

**The last edit:**

For `N x N` case, use `\Populate{0}{N-1}{N}` to avoid having an extra job to remove the leading commas above. (I just got this enlightenment)

Comment: Are you sure that `tikz-pgf` tag is necessary? ;-)

Comment: @PolGab: Maybe because of its scope behavior. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use more groups (`{...}`) to localize (re)definition of your macros `\ups` and `rights`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen,pgf}

\parindent=0pt

\newcommand{\Populate}[3]%
{%
  \ifthenelse{#2=0}% on the most left border?
  {% 
    \ifthenelse{#3=0}% on the most top border?
    {% 
      #1\endgraf% I need to trim the most left comma later!
    }%
    {%
        % move upward
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ups}{#3-1}%
        \Populate{#1,1}{#2}{\ups}%
    }%  
  }%      
  {% 
    \ifthenelse{#2=#3}% on the diagonal border?
    {%
        % move to the right
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rights}{#2-1}%
        \Populate{#1,0}{\rights}{#3}%
    }%
    {%
      {% GROUP
        % move to the right
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rights}{#2-1}%
        \Populate{#1,0}{\rights}{#3}%
      }%
        % move upward
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ups}{#3-1}%
        \Populate{#1,1}{#2}{\ups}%
    }%
  }%      
}


\begin{document}
\Populate{}{4}{4}
\end{document}
```

**Remark**: a *macro* is not a *function*. Your question should be "How to make a recursive macro in (La)TeX?".

Comment: I prefer the *control words* `\bgroup` and `\egroup` to the curly braces `{` and `}` because I can avoid appending `%` and too deep nested scoping.

Comment: @HiggsBoson `\bgroup` starts a new scope just the same as `{`.  And it is longer than `{%`.

Comment: @RyanReich: But my eyes locates the scoping pair much better when using `\bgroup` and `\egroup`.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest version I can do. If you have more simpler one, please edit this answer.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\newcount\u
\newcount\r

\def\d#1{\advance#1-1\relax}

\newcommand{\Populate}[3]{%
        \r#2\u#3%
        \ifnum\r=0
                \ifnum\u=0\relax
                        #1\endgraf
                \else
                        \d\u\Populate{#1,1}{#2}{\the\u}%
                \fi
        \else
                \ifnum\r=\u
                        \d\r\Populate{#1,0}{\the\r}{#3}%
                \else                       
                        {\d\r\Populate{#1,0}{\the\r}{#3}}% must be grouped!
                        \d\u\Populate{#1,1}{#2}{\the\u}%
                \fi
        \fi}


\begin{document}
\Populate{0}{3}{4}
\end{document}
```