# How to create rectangles like in this example?

Tags: graphics

I want to draw rectangles like the exmaple below in my tex file. I am trying to illustrate the path counting problem on a rectangular mesh.

[image]

Comment: Try [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63540/how-to-draw-a-catalan-number-diagram-on-tikz/63591) to see if the answers there sufficiently answer your question.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are "too localized". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: @ScottH. unfortunately, I want rectangles but not squares and I am a newbie. Where can I learn how to make this code for rectangles? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not really a newbie question.  You might add a comment to one of the answers in the linked question and see if they would be willing to generalize the code to include rectangles.

Comment: @ScottH. unfortunately I don't have the privilege to post comment on someone else's post!

Comment: In the first code block in the first answer to the linked question, change `\newcommand\catalannumber[3]` to `\newcommand\catalannumber[4]` and in the code change `#3` to `#4`, `(#2,#2)` to `(#2,#3)` and invoke as `\catalannumber{0,0}{2}{3}{0,1,1,1,0};`

Comment: @Naji Your example contains only squares. Can you show an example with real rectangles?

Comment: @PaulGaborit, I asked the question somewhere else and got the answer already:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107097/what-is-the-for-in-tikz