# What is the "#" for in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I am a newbie and I asked in [How to create rectangles like in this example?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107076/how-to-create-rectangles-like-in-this-example) about how to make some rectangles. I am trying to read the code and understand it as I need rectangles rather than squares. But I cannot find in the net what this #1 to #4 are? As the notation is short I can't even search it up.
So I would be happy if somebody helps me with it.

```
\newcommand\catalannumber[3]{
  % start point, size, Dyck word (size x 2 booleans)
  \fill[cyan!25]  (#1) rectangle +(#2,#2);
  \fill[fill=lime]
  (#1)
  \foreach \dir in {#3}{
    \ifnum\dir=0
    -- ++(1,0)
    \else
    -- ++(0,1)
    \fi
  } |- (#1);
  \draw[help lines] (#1) grid +(#2,#2);
  \draw[dashed] (#1) -- +(#2,#2);
  \coordinate (prev) at (#1);
  \foreach \dir in {#3}{
    \ifnum\dir=0
    \coordinate (dep) at (1,0);
    \else
    \coordinate (dep) at (0,1);
    \fi
    \draw[line width=2pt,-stealth] (prev) -- ++(dep) coordinate (prev);
  };
}
```

Comment: `#1` and so on have nothing to do with TikZ; they represent the arguments: when you call `\catalannumber{arg1}{arg2}{arg3}`, `#1` will be replaced by `arg1` and so on.

Comment: The # has little to do with TikZ. It's used in the expression of formal parameters in the definition of a command (here: `\catalannumber`). In lay terms, "#1" refers to the first argument passed to `\catalannumber`, "#2" refers to the second argument, etc.

Comment: Also a good read [What's the meaning of `##` symbol in an argument](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42463/what-is-the-meaning-of-double-pound-symbol-1-in-an-argument)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "#" has little to do with TikZ. It's used in the expression of formal parameters in the definition of a command (here: `\catalannumber`). In lay terms, `#1` refers to the first argument passed to `\catalannumber`, `#2` refers to the second argument, etc.

I'm not familiar with Catalan numbers, so I'm not even sure that what follows makes any mathematical sense, but if you want to get a rectangular lattice instead of a square one, you can adapt the code from [How to draw a Catalan number diagram on TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63540/how-to-draw-a-catalan-number-diagram-on-tikz) as follows.
The second argument to `\catalannumberrectangle` is "m,n", where "m" is the number of columns and "n" is the number of rows of the lattice.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\catalannumberrectangle[3]{
  % start point, size, Dyck word (size x 2 booleans)
  \fill[cyan!25]  (#1) rectangle +(#2);
  \fill[fill=lime]
  (#1)
  \foreach \dir in {#3}{
    \ifnum\dir=0
    -- ++(1,0)
    \else
    -- ++(0,1)
    \fi
  } |- (#1);
  \draw[help lines] (#1) grid +(#2);
  \draw[dashed] (#1) -- +(#2);
  \coordinate (prev) at (#1);
  \foreach \dir in {#3}{
    \ifnum\dir=0
    \coordinate (dep) at (1,0);
    \else
    \coordinate (dep) at (0,1);
    \fi
    \draw[line width=2pt,-stealth] (prev) -- ++(dep) coordinate (prev);
  };
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \catalannumberrectangle{0,-9}{8,4}{0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you please also tell me why I get this:
http://i46.tinypic.com/21eyubn.jpg

Rather than the one like yours?

Comment: this is what I run:\catalannumberrectangle{0,-4}{4,5}{0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1};

Comment: Do you mean that you get a different result with the code from my answer? If so, you might want to check that you have the latest version of PGF/TikZ. Or do you mean that you want to get an output like in the picture you link to?

Comment: no I want my result to look like yours. Mine is only showing a lime triangle as you can see! I will try to update my TikZ then...

Comment: problem solved after updating. Thanks again.